# How to get lists of descendant tip names of a data.tree object recursively?

Tags: r, data.tree

I'm using the `data.tree` package in R and I have a tree like the one below, where only the leaf nodes have labels. I am trying to assign attributes that are lists of the descendants (we can assume the tree is always bifurcating).

```
tree <- read.tree(text = "((A,B),C);")
tree <- as.Node(tree)
print(tree)
```

```
  levelName
1 4        
2  ¦--5    
3  ¦   ¦--A
4  ¦   °--B
5  °--C
```

So what I'm looking for is something like this, except for node `4` the attribute should be `(A,B)` where it says `5`.

```
tree$Do(function(node) node$desc1 <- as.vector(sapply(node$children, function(x) x$name))[1],
         traversal = "post-order", filterFun = isNotLeaf)
tree$Do(function(node) node$desc2 <- as.vector(sapply(node$children, function(x) x$name))[2],
         traversal = "post-order", filterFun = isNotLeaf)
print(tree, "desc1", "desc2")
```

```
  levelName desc1 desc2
1 4             5     C
2  ¦--5         A     B
3  ¦   ¦--A            
4  ¦   °--B            
5  °--C
```

So I don't just need the children node names, I need it to recursively save the descendant names as lists and assign them as it goes from tips to root.

```
  levelName desc1 desc2
1 4           (A,B)   C
2  ¦--5         A     B
3  ¦   ¦--A            
4  ¦   °--B            
5  °--C
```

Big picture: I eventually will need to traverse the tree and pass these lists into another function i.e. `doSomething( group1 = "C", group2 = c("A","B") )` and save the output of that function as an attribute of the internal nodes.

The closest I've gotten is this recursive function but it gives the same output as above

```
getDescendant <- function(node) {
  if(node$isLeaf == FALSE) {
    result <- as.vector(sapply(node$children, function(x) x$name))
  } else {
    result <-sapply(node$children, getDescendant)
  }
  return(result)
}
print(tree, desc = getDescendant)
```

```
  levelName desc
1 4         5, C
2  ¦--5     A, B
3  ¦   ¦--A     
4  ¦   °--B     
5  °--C
```

EDIT: Here is what I got to work, but it's not generalizable to trees that aren't bifurcating.

```
tree  <- read.tree(text = "((A,B),C);")
tree <- as.Node(tree)

########## Collect descendant clades for each node
get_descendants <- function(node) {
  if(node$children[[1]]$isLeaf == TRUE && node$children[[2]]$isLeaf == TRUE) {
    node$desc1 <- node$children[[1]]$name
    node$desc2 <- node$children[[2]]$name
  } else if(node$children[[1]]$isLeaf == FALSE && node$children[[2]]$isLeaf == FALSE) {
    node$desc1 <- c(as.vector(node$children[[1]]$desc1), as.vector(node$children[[1]]$desc2))
    node$desc2 <- c(as.vector(node$children[[2]]$desc1), as.vector(node$children[[2]]$desc2))
  } else {
    if(node$children[[1]]$isLeaf == TRUE && node$children[[2]]$isLeaf == FALSE) {
      node$desc1 <- node$children[[1]]$name
      node$desc2 <- c(as.vector(node$children[[2]]$desc1), as.vector(node$children[[2]]$desc2))
    } else {
      node$desc1 <- c(as.vector(node$children[[1]]$desc1), as.vector(node$children[[1]]$desc2))
      node$desc2 <- node$children[[2]]$name
    }
  }
}
tree$Do(function(node) get_descendants(node), filterFun=isNotLeaf, 
         traversal = "post-order")
print(tree, "desc1", "desc2")
```

```
  levelName desc1 desc2
1 4          A, B     C
2  ¦--5         A     B
3  ¦   ¦--A            
4  ¦   °--B            
5  °--C
```